# RegEx .replace() is not working

Tags: javascript

```
RegEx = new RegExp(sourcevalue, "gi");

temp[i] = Selectors[i].cssText.replace(RegEx, targetvalue);
```

where `sourcevalue = rgb(255,0,0)` and `targetvalue = #FFFFFF`, but `sourcevalue` is not replaced by `targetvalue`, why?

Comment: Could you do the same on jsfiddle but with trivial variables, not `Selectors[i].cssText`

Comment: Show all the relevant code. Parens are special characters in regexes, have you escaped them properly?

Comment: WHy would `sourcevalue` be changed? The result is in `temp[i]`. You coded that!

Comment: @leppie No my grandmom coded this

Comment: @gaurav: It appears she has a better understanding than you do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because sourcevalue is a correct Javascript regular expression but it's not working the way you expected. There are special characters in regular expression like the () parentheses. They are used to group parts of regular expressions. To use them with their "literal" meaing you'll have to escape them using backslashes

```
var RegEx = /rgb\(255,0,0\)/gi;
```

Answer (score 4):

Most likely because you did not escape the parenthesis properly:

```
var sourcevalue = "rgb\\(255,0,0\\)";
```

Parenthesis are used for grouping/back-referencing matches. If you want to match them *literally*, you have to escape them with `\`. Since `sourcevalue` is a string and `\` is the  escape character in a string as well, you have to escape the backslash to create a literal one.

Otherwise, the expression would match `rgb255,0,0` but not `rgb(255,0,0)`.